# Setup Antmedia Video streaming with custom camera

Tags: android, android-camera, ant-media-server-sdk

I am new in video streaming related project! I Create a streaming server with ant media. Its working fine with `opengl GLSurfaceView`. But I want to replace this GLSurfaceView with custom cameraview. But I'm unable to figure out how to do it. I seen an opensource project on github: https://github.com/natario1/CameraView

I want use this camera view as stream source.

I'm done with below code:

```
LiveVideoBroadcaster.LocalBinder binder = (LiveVideoBroadcaster.LocalBinder) service;
            if (mLiveVideoBroadcaster == null) {
                mLiveVideoBroadcaster = binder.getService();
                mLiveVideoBroadcaster.init(LiveVideoBroadcasterActivity.this, mGLView);
                mLiveVideoBroadcaster.setAdaptiveStreaming(true);
            }
            mLiveVideoBroadcaster.openCamera(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
```

Here mGLView is GLSurfaceView I want replace it with this custom camera view. Can anyone suggest from where can I start?